# Bind param with OR Condition Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, binding

I am using bind Params for MySQL Queries

```
    $variation_type = 'classification';
    $currentSku = 1212;
    $enrollBind =  array('parent_sku' => $currentSku,'variation_type' =>  $variation_type);
    $enrollQuery = "select variation_value 
         from product_map 
         where parent_sku =:parent_sku 
         and variation_type =:variation_type 
         and variation_value <>'' 
         group by variation_value";
```

My Question is I need to use OR condition in the query that is

```
$variation_type = 'classification';
```

or

```
$variation_type = 'test';
```

How can I Use this OR condition in Bind Param?

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: the or condition is not in bind param but in sql code  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN` to compare with multiple values, e.g.:

```
$enrollQuery = "select variation_value 
from product_map 
where parent_sku =:parent_sku and variation_type IN('classification', 'test')
and variation_value <>'' group by variation_value";
```

For php, you can bind it in different variables and use it in query like `variation_type IN(:classification_type, :test_type)`

**Update**

You can pass two values as different parameters, e.g.:

```
$classification_variation_type = 'classification';
$test_variation_type = 'test';
$enrollBind =  array('parent_sku' => $currentSku,'classification_variation_type' =>  $classification_variation_type, 'test_variation_type' => $test_variation_type);
    $enrollQuery = "select variation_value 
         from product_map 
         where parent_sku =:parent_sku 
         and variation_type = IN(:classification_variation_type, :test_variation_type)
         and variation_value <>'' 
         group by variation_value";
```

Comment: Updated the answer @jafarpinjar